# I don't know how to leave this looping structure

Tags: java, bluej

Ok, so the code below loops wonderfully. It can loop as long as it wants to. The thing is though, I can never get out of the loop. I'm trying to build a text-adventure, by the way for those wondering, but I really need to get out of this loop.

```
    System.out.println("\n\nWelcome, " + name + "! To proceed, enter your class of fighter.");
    System.out.println();
    boolean x = true;
    while (x){
        //information print statements

        System.out.println("What will your class be?  ");
        String heroclass = scan.nextLine();
        heroclass.toLowerCase();
        String A;
        switch (heroclass)
        {
            case "slayer": A = "You have selected the Slayer class.";
            break;
            case "blader": A = "You have selected the Blader class.";
            break;
            case "bandit": A = "You have selected the Bandit class.";
            break;
            case "wizard": A = "You have selected the Wizard class.";
            break;
            default: A = "Invalid entry.";
            break;
        }
        String killloop = A;
        if (killloop.charAt(0) == 'Y'){
            x = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What inputs did you try?

Comment: I used "Slayer", "Blader", Bandit", and "Wizard" to try to get a good answer out of it. I then tried "Fir Tree" to get the bad response, but it just kept looping.

Comment: You'll be asking the user for input more than once, I imagine. Maybe you should pull the looping/validation logic out into a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign `heroclass.toLowerCase();` to the original value of `heroclass`:

```
heroclass = heroclass.toLowerCase();
```

If you do not do this, the lowercase version of heroclass is not saved.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I'll implement it immediately.

Comment: If you ever have an error again, try checking the value of different variables at different points in the code. That way you could have seen that the value of heroclass was not really made lowercase. If this fixes your problem please accept the answer and follow up my advice.

Comment: I will, thanks. This is a tip I'll do my best to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Put your loop in a labeled block:

```
myblock: {
    while (true) {
        //code
        heroclass = heroclass.toLowerCase();
        switch(heroclass)
        {
            case "slayer": A = "text";
                break myblock;

            //repeat with other cases
        }
    }
}
//goes to here when you say "break myblock;"
```

What you're doing is basically assigning the label `myblock` to the entire loop.  When you say `break myblock` it breaks out of the entire section inside of the brackets.

NOTE: I would recommend this solution over the others because it doesn't depend on the magic value assigned by the `switch`; it works no matter what it is.

Also, I've added the part to make it case insensitive.  Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: This isn't the root issue, see The Coding Wombat's answer.

Comment: I know, but I don't think s/he should be using the String validation at all; it just introduces an unnecessary magic value.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, this fixes nothing. Also my solution does not depend on a "magic" value but on simple assignment logic

Comment: @ostrichofevil Your answer improves on the original code, but still would be cut short by the same issue that breaks the original code. On top of that, your answer still presents a non-ideal way of approach this (instead, something like a `if classList.contains(inputClass) break;` statement would be considerably nicer).

Comment: It's just simpler if you don't have to worry about Strings and their values, and also slightly more efficient.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with you that this code is a lot cleaner @ostrichofevil but if the user enters a value like "Slayer" it won't work since slayer != Slayer. If you would substitue heroclass for heroclass.toLowerCase() in the switch statement this would solve the actual problem.

Comment: Oh wait, I misunderstood your problem.  Sorry! @TheCodingWombat  I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

heroclass is of String type. String is immutable type of object, so you can't update this string. heroclass.toLowerCase() just return another String object with lower cased characters, so you need to reassign this string result to this variable:

```
heroclass = heroclass.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although coding wombat is right, i'm not a big fan of the way you did things here. A loop around your whole program like this isn't good practice. It's super clunky and will lead to many problems, not to mention you're making things more complicated for yourself. Ideally you'd want to put this class selection part of the program inside a method. Then if the user's input is invalid, simply call back the method recursively until you get correct input.

Ex.

case A: do this...

case B: do this...

case C: System.out.println("Not a valid input);, classSelector();

Also, when you use OOP you have the benefit of storing all the player's attributes inside an object, as well as making methods that manipulates those attributes. It will make your code a lot cleaner and easier to work with.

Ex.

Player1.heal(10);

Comment: Though I have to agree with you on some of this, this does not answer the asker's question and should be a comment to my answer or his question instead of an answer by itself.